# Pulling out values form a CURL call

Tags: php, arrays, curl

New to this but trying to get my head around things. Been looking into this a lot but can't get it to work for me. I can initiate a CURL call and bring back results but I am having difficulty picking out certain parts from what is returned. Have been trying so many different things I'm getting a little lost learning in the process but can't workout why this is not working for me.

```
  1. <?php
  2. $address= $_GET['postcode']; //this is putting postcode into the URL postcode defined in the HTML which is working with var_dump.
  3. $curl = curl_init();
  4. curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  5. CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  6. CURLOPT_URL =>
  7. 'https://url=json'   //url would normally have the address i'm going to
  8. ) );
  9. $locator =curl_exec( $curl );
 10. $json = json_decode( $locator, true );
 11.
 12. echo $json['address'];
 13.
 14. curl_close ($curl);
```

--

This is the results from a var_dump($json);

```
array(2) { 
    ["spatialReference"]=> array(2) { 
        ["wkid"]=> int(27700) 
        ["latestWkid"]=> int(27700) 
    } 
    ["candidates"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(4) { 
            ["address"]=> string(91) "CANTERBURY EAST AMBULANCE COMMUNITY RESPONSE POST, MILITARY ROAD, CANTERBURY, KENT, CT1 1YW" 
            ["location"]=> array(2) { 
                ["x"]=> float(615849.72) 
                ["y"]=> float(158383.86) 
            } 
            ["score"]=> int(100) 
            ["attributes"]=> array(73) { 
                ["Match_addr"]=> string(91) "CANTERBURY EAST AMBULANCE COMMUNITY RESPONSE POST, MILITARY ROAD, CANTERBURY, KENT, CT1 1YW" 
                ["Addr_type"]=> string(7) "Address"
```

I am getting an error,

> Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kevin\search.php on line 12

I have tried this with "address" to no effect in the case it was something like that but from what I have been looking at don't think it would have been this.

Looking to use a `foreach` statement eventually for this but though just pulling through some data might be a good first step.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess and say that it's in `$json['candidates'][0]['address']` ... and that you're probably going to want to loop through *candidates*.

Comment: It's hard to guess the address key belongs to which index. If possible provide the JSON or can give a try to @CD001's solution

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your var_dump output so it is more obvious. @CD001 is correct. What you will want to do is something like this (untested):

```
$candidates = $json['candidates'];
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
    $address = $candidate['address'];
    echo ("Candidate address is: " . $address);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this is returning the address and nothing else. Now I just need to understand what is happening here looks as though I was using 'address' as the array but 'address' is an array of 'candidates' in a way. Thanks food for though for me.